# VSCode Solidity Visual Developper Audit tags

Tags: solidity, security, visual-studio-code

I was just wondering if anyone knew of a comprehensive list of all the @audit tags available on the Consensys plugin in vscode.

I know of those 4: @audit, @audit-info, @audit-ok, @audit-issue.

Wondering if there are more or if there is a list available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@audit-info - used for General bookmark for information to be noted for later use.

See: https://github.com/sambacha/audit-format

Comment: Awesome, so only those 4 audit tags then. Thanks!